# Show that for $\xi>1,$ $A \text{ is } \Delta_{\xi+1}^0 \iff A=\lim_nA_n\text{ for some } A_n\in\Delta_\xi^0.$

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Problem below (kuratowski) is taken from [Kechris's Classical Descriptive Set Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387943749), page $173.$

---

*Definition*: Given any sequence of sets $(A_n),$ $A_n\subseteq X,$ let 
$$\overline{\lim_n} \, A_n = \bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m = \{x:x\text{ belongs to infinitely many } A_n\},$$
$$\underline{\lim}_n \, A_n = \bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m = \{x:x\text{ belongs to all but finitely many } A_n\},$$
It is clear that $\underline{\lim}_n \, A_n \subseteq\overline{\lim_n} \, A_n.$ 
If they are equal, let 
$$\lim_n A_n= \overline{\lim_n} \, A_n = \underline{\lim}_n \, A_n .$$

Assume now that $X$ is metrizable, so that every closed set is a $G_\delta$ set. 
Let $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal, and for $1\leq \xi<\omega_1,$ define by transfinite recursion the classes $\Sigma_\xi^0,\Pi_\xi^0$ of subsets of $X$ as follows:

$$\Sigma_1^0=\{U\subseteq X: U \text{ is open}\},$$
$$\Pi_\xi^0 =\sim\Sigma_\xi^0,$$
$$\Sigma_\xi^0=\bigg\{ \bigcup_n A_n: A_n\in \Pi_{\xi_n}^0, \xi_n<\xi, n\in\mathbb{N} \bigg\}, \text{ if } \xi>1,$$
where $\sim$ refers to set complement.
In addition, let 
$$\Delta_\xi^0 = \Sigma_\xi^0\cap \Pi_\xi^0.$$

For example, $\Sigma_1^0$ is a topology on $X$ where $\Pi_1^0$ is the collection of closed sets of $X.$
$\Sigma_2^0$ is the collection of all $F_\sigma$ sets while $\Pi_2^0$ is the collection of all $G_\delta$ sets.
Note that $\Delta_1^0$ is the collection of all closed and open sets while $\Delta_2^0$ is the collection of all $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ sets.

---

> *Question* (Kuratowski) : Show that for $\xi>1,$
>   $$A \text{ is } \Delta_{\xi+1}^0 \iff A=\lim_nA_n\text{ for some sequence } (A_n) \text{ with } A_n\in\Delta_\xi^0.$$

For $(\Leftarrow)$ direction, by definition, 
$$A = \bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m = \bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m.$$
If $A_m\in\Delta_\xi^0 = \Sigma_\xi^0\cap \Pi_\xi^0,$ then
$$\bigcup_{m\geq n}A_m\in \Sigma_{\xi}^0\quad \text{and}\quad \bigcap_{m\geq n}A_m\in\Pi_\xi^0.$$
Then by definition of $\Sigma_{\xi+1}^0$ and $\Pi_{\xi+1}^0,$ we have 
$$ \bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m\in \Pi_{\xi+1}^0\quad\text{and}\quad \bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m\in\Sigma_{\xi+1}^0.$$

I have no idea on how to start $(\Rightarrow)$ direction.

Comment: You know, the lim inf and lim sup are very common and pretty easy to recognize, even when you are using a less common symbol for them. But the $\Delta, \sum, \prod$ notations you are using are far less common. I suggest explaining them instead of lim inf and lim sup.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Thanks for mentioning the unusual symbols. I have included their definitions in my question.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Those notations are pretty common as well in descriptive set theory and in logic.

Comment: @Régis Do you know how to answer my questions?

Comment: I used to but I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**
This only holds if $\xi$ is successor ordinal.

To prove ($\Leftarrow$), first since $A \in \Delta_{\xi+1}^0, A\in\Sigma_{\xi+1}^0$ and $A\in\Pi_{\xi+1}^0$. So 
$$
A=\bigcup_nB_n=\bigcap_nC_n, \quad B_n\in \Delta_{\xi}^0,\: C_n\in\Delta_{\xi}^0
$$
Where $B_n\subset B_{n+1}\subset \cdots\subset A\subset \cdots\subset C_{n+1}\subset C_{n}$. Thus there is $A_n\in \Delta_{\xi}^0$ that $B_n\subset A_n\subset C_n$. Clearly 
$$
\overline{\lim_n} \, A_n = \bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m \subset \bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n} C_m =\bigcap_n C_n=A
$$
And
$$
\underline{\lim}_n \, A_n = \bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n} A_m \supset \bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n} B_m=\bigcup_n B_n =A
$$
Thus $A=\lim_{n}A_n$.